# Implement chrono time in Linux and Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, linux, c++-chrono

I need to record the elapsed time in microseconds for my program and I used chrono in c++. It is compulsory for my assignment to run in Linux environment. Problem is when I run this in Linux Ubuntu in a virtual box(have included -std=c++11), the result is way shorter than when I run this code in Visual Studio 2017. The difference is 2000++ microseconds. Perhaps someone know why the result in both places are different?

```
auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();   //record the starting time
{ 
    //function call
}

auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();   //record the finish time 
double elapsed_time = double(chrono::duration_cast <chrono::microseconds> (end - start).count()); // elapsed time
time.push_back(elapsed_time);  //vector<double>time that collect all the times
```

Comment: Measuring time is not really an exact science. Code may run faster or slower on different machines and/or operating systems. Or I misunderstand your question?

Comment: *"seems to be correct"*... how do you determine the *correct* time for a function to run? How do you know how long it *should* take?

Comment: @DeiDei i think you didnt misunderstand. I have compiled the kernel to the lastest version before due to assignment but do you think this could be the reason why(maybe something gone wrong in kernel compilation)? or maybe it is just the code runs faster in linux than visual studio in windows 10.

Comment: @Galik, you are right, im not sure if it is correct or not. I will edit the post again.

Comment: You are running in a virtual machine, without direct access to the hardware clock and with multiple layers of software between your code and the hardware - inaccurate measurements seem like "the way of the game" to me. Why would you even expect accurate results in that situation?

Comment: @Jesper Juhl ohh yeah that's true I didnt think about that point of multiple layers of software between the code and hardware. Thank you for ur pinpoint.